# Solutions for tracking pixels on 3rd party sites?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, tracking, ads

My business works with affiliates to whom we send traffic, and when a signup happens on their site, we are paid. We need a way to confirm that what they're reporting to us is accurate and trustable - so we gave them a pixel hosted on our site that would be implemented on their conversion page. Unfortunately, the data seems extremely off, and they're saying it's our pixel - not their reporting system. They recommended we get them a "Google Pixel, javascript if possible".

I've been trying to figure out how / where to do this or set this up. Any clues, guys?

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you need to do is set up your implementation to track additional domains:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite

Give them the javascript snippet GA provides to you and then set up a conversion goal for their conversion page (thank you page?).  I would have them put that snippet of code on every page leading up to the conversion page and then declare it in the goal steps in case you planned on ever analyzing where your traffic might be dropping off in the funnel reports.

EDIT:  It's important that they don't have their own GA account tracking the page because (from Google):

https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/concepts/gaConceptsCookies#top

> Multiple Analytics Accounts on a Given Page
>
> Some users want to track the same page or set of pages in multiple Analytics Accounts. >Analytics is designed to work effectively with a single account-to-web-property >relationship. If you have multiple accounts tracking the same web property (e.g. page or >sets of pages), both accounts will read from and set the same set of cookies. This set up >is generally not recommended.